# Forcing a python program to interpret using python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, windows-7

I have python 2.7.6 and python 3.4 installed on windows 7 machine.

When I open command prompt for windows and type python, python 2.7.6 starts by default.

I have a python script which I want to compile (or interpret officially speaking) using python 3.4.

Is there a command to use python 3.4 from c:/ prompt? or make 3.4 the default python interpreter?

thanks

Comment: Does typing 'python3' work, out of curiousity?

Comment: Alright. I'm not a Python+Windows person, but this should be able to help you out: https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent versions of Python for Windows install a script called `py` that will do what you want.

You can either do `py -3 script.py` to explicitly tell the launcher that you want to use Python 3

or put something containing "python3" on the first line in a comment (ideally `#!/usr/bin/env python3` for compatibility with other systems...) and just run `script.py`; the installer associates `*.py` files with the launcher, which in turn determines the version to run by looking at the first line of the script.

This mechanism is described in [PEP 397](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/).

Comment: [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) probably allows to specify the default Python version that is used by `py` command and Python scripts unless they specify otherwise in their shebang lines. Make sure that `.py`, `.pyw` extensions are associated with the launcher.

Comment: thanks :) @ Wooble it worked !! I will accept the answer in 8 minutes :) the site wouldn't let me click on the arrow now !

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that you are always running python 3, you can modify your Windows PATH Environment variable to include the python 3 directory, and remove the python 2 directory.